# Proving a greedy algorithm can obtain the optimal solution under certain circumstances

Tags: graph-theory

For the graph coloring problem:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

I am trying to design a greedy algorithm to solve it *fast*. The graph is not planar nor forming a particular structure. [Brooks' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem)  ensures you need at most $\Delta+1$ colors to give color to any graph whose maximum degree is $\Delta$.

So the question is:

If I limit the number of colors from which the **selection function** can choose, Will this...

1. always find a feasible solution? **(*)**
2. ensure the optimal solution in the case that the graph needs exactly $\Delta+1$ colors?

The second question seems to be an obvious *yes*, as the **selection function** will not use more than $\Delta +1$ colors. But, still, the first question needs to be answered.

Note: A [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) uses a selection function to make the *locally optimal choice* at each stage with the hope of finding a global optimum. The locally optimal choice is not clear here. I will probably use the approach of Welsh-Powell.

Note 2: The question is somewhat equivalent to:

- Does the Welsh-Powell algorithm obtain the optimal solution when the graph's chromatic number is exactly $\Delta+1$.

**(*)** Feasible means that all graph nodes need to be colored at the end of the algorithm.

Comment: Hi again :)  I think you misread Brooke's Theorem.  Actually, all graphs can be colored with at most $\Delta$ colors EXCEPT two of them, which need $\Delta + 1$ colors.  They are the complete graph and the cycle of odd length.  So to answer your Note 2 question, you can just try the algorithm on these two vertices.  The answer is Yes.

Comment: By vertices I meant graphs (near the end of the previous comment)

Comment: Yes, I undertood the theorem and used the upper bound. The question could be reformuled to: Excluding those two graphs that need $\Delta+1$ colors to be colored... Now change every $\Delta+1$ in the OP for $\Delta$.